# Ambiguous? Notation for Cross-Correlation

Tags: notation

Is it true that

$f(t)\star g(-t)$

is not the same as

$f(t)\star h(t)$

if $h(t)=g(-t)$?

($\star$ means cross-correlation).

The example I was thinking of was if $g(t)=t$. Then
$(f(t)\star g(-t))(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)(-t+\tau)d\tau$,
but $(f(t)\star h(t))(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)(-(t+\tau))d\tau=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)(-t-\tau)d\tau$.

If it's true then wouldn't something like $t^2\star -t$ be ambiguous?

I think I'm most likely making a mistake here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like $t^2\star -t$ is understandable.  Since you didn't define $\star$, I'm not sure if or where you made a mistake.

The $f(t)*g(-t)$ is convenient notation and is very common in engineering texts. It's convenient, because it's easier to write $f(t)*g(-t)$ than to write this with more conventional function notation: 
$$(f*h)(t),$$
where $h(t) = g(-t)$, and be forced to define a new function $h$.

The downside to convenience is that it mixes together the function's "name" and "argument", and can lead to awkward expressions like $(f(t)*g(-t))(t)$ if you want to evaluate this at some point $t$.

Comment: Thanks b yen. In this case, would $(f\star h)(t)$ be a different function (flipped about the y axis) from $(f\star g(-t))(t)$ though?

Comment: If you define $h(t) = g(-t)$, then $(f\star h)(t) = (f\star g(-t))(t)$ are the same function. If you write down your definition of $\star$, it would easier to understand what your wrote in your question.

Comment: Hi, I think I was just confused because wikipedia said: "the convolution $f*g$ (equivalent to the cross-correlation of f(t) and g(−t) ) ". I interpreted this as $f*g = f\star g(-t)$, but it should really be $f*g = g(-t)\star f$, right?